# Accessing in array object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, search, find

is there a way to access the 'inq' key's value in one line of code in javascript?

```
[  
   {  
      "start_date":{  
         "gt":"2017-12-12 00:00:00"
      }
   },
   {  
      "start_date":{  
         "lt":"2017-12-13 23:59:59"
      }
   },
   {  
      "active":"true"
   },
   {  
      "city_ids":{  
         "inq":[  
            1006
         ]
      }
   }
]
```

I don't want to do for loops and all.
A simple one line code in javascript would be great.
The format is not fixed, city_ids can come either first, second or anywhere.

Comment: foo[3].city_ids.inq[0] ?

Comment: Is the format fixed, or can it change?

Comment: The format is not fixed, city_ids can come either first, second or anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *array.prototype.find* to find the element which have *city_ids* and *inq* property

```js
var arr = [  
   {  
      "start_date":{  
         "gt":"2017-12-12 00:00:00"
      }
   },
   {  
      "start_date":{  
         "lt":"2017-12-13 23:59:59"
      }
   },
   {  
      "active":"true"
   },
   {  
      "city_ids":{  
         "inq":[  
            1006
         ]
      }
   }
];

var value = arr.find(e => e.city_ids && e.city_ids.inq)['city_ids']['inq'];
console.log(value);
```

Comment: 0% compatibility with IE

Comment: Both the use of arrow functions and `Array.prototype.find()` (by the way).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```js
let data = [  
   {  
      "start_date":{  
         "gt":"2017-12-12 00:00:00"
      }
   },
   {  
      "start_date":{  
         "lt":"2017-12-13 23:59:59"
      }
   },
   {  
      "active":"true"
   },
   {  
      "city_ids":{  
         "inq":[  
            1006
         ]
      }
   }
]

console.log(data[3].city_ids.inq[0])
```